# Являются ли обстоятельства однородными и, соответственно, нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Измерение происходит **полностью автоматически**[,] **в течение 6 часов**.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, эти обстоятельства не являются однородными, ведь одно из них – обстоятельство образа действия, другое – времени. В зависимости от воли автора, обстоятельство времени можно считать или не считать уточнением, в первом случае его нужно  обособить, во втором запятая не нужна.